# Change background image when app rotates

Tags: iphone

I am making an universal app, but only support rotation on iPad so here it goes:

I have a view that has a image as background. When the user rotates the iPad I fade this portrait image out in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and replaces the image with a landscape image in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`, and this is working great! (If there are better ways I want to hear them, but this question is not about this though).

I have one button on this view that will push a new viewcontroller on the stack. This view controller also has the same "function" as the view that it was pushed from. What I need help with is: When I rotates the iPad from portrait (which was the orientation this view was pushed on from) to landscape the image in this "second" view changes as intended. However when I pop this viewcontroller off stack the "first" view still displays the image which is made for portrait and not the landscape one...I understand why but not how I should fix this.

Could anyone help me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can save the device orientation (check UIDevice documentation) on your viewWillDisappear: and check it on the viewWillAppear: method, calling the animation if necessary.

Comment: @Marcelo Yes, that is a possibility.

Comment: @Marcelo Hi, I did implement what you said and I think it was a nice and simple way of doing it. Thank you. I think you should move your comment to an answer so I can accept it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the device orientation (check UIDevice documentation) on your viewWillDisappear: and check it on the viewWillAppear: method, calling the animation if necessary.

(the OP told me to post it as answer)

Answer (score 1):

You could always register for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification and change the image if the controller is not on the top stack.

Assuming you're using a UINavigationController (since you mentioned pushing controllers), you could figure out if the controller is on top by:

```
if ([[self navigationController] topViewController] == self) {
    // do magic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the first view controller's `viewWillAppear` method. In there, you can find the device's orientation by calling `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` and set the background image accordingly.